# Contact form returns blank page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, contacts

I'm working on a little website for a game server and I have some troubles making the contact form work, when I click on submit it return a blank page and doesn't send the e-mail. Here is the code, HTML and PHP

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
<div>
<div class="row">
<div class="6u">
<input type="text" name="senderName" id="name" placeholder="Nume" />
</div>
<div class="6u">
<input type="text" name="senderEmail" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="6u">
<input type="text" name="senderUsername" id="name" placeholder="Username Minecraft" />
</div>
<div class="6u">
<input type="text" name="senderMethod" id="email" placeholder="Modalitate de plata (PayPal sau PaySafeCard)" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="12u">
<textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Mesaj Optional (in caz ca vrei sa adaugi ceva)"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row double">
<div class="12u">
<ul class="actions">
<li><input type="submit" value="Trimite" /></li>
<li><input type="reset" value="Reseteaza" class="alt" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if($_POST["submit"]) {
$recipient="outsidebbr@yahoo.com";
$subject="Test";
$senderName = $_POST['senderName']
$senderEmail = $_POST['senderEmail'] ;
$senderUsermame = $_POST['senderUsermame']
$senderMethod = $_POST['senderMethod']
$message = $_POST['message'] ;


mail( $recipient, $subject, "From: $senderEmail", $message);
header( "Location: form-thankyou.html" ); }
?>
```

Anyone can help please? Thanks!

Comment: you missed name of the submit button `<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Trimite" />` and again a submit button with `name="submit"` is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few reasons why this doesn't work:

1. `if ($_POST["submit"])` doesn't work!

   - **Workaround:** Add name to the submit button `<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />`
2. Syntax errors missing `;` in PHP.

   - **Workaround:** Add semicolons at the end of the lines:

     ```
     $senderName = $_POST['senderName']
     $senderUsermame = $_POST['senderUsermame']
     $senderMethod = $_POST['senderMethod']
     ```
3. You are reusing the same `id` in multiple controls.

   - **Workaround:** Use different `id`s for multiple controls.
4. You are not running it in a web server!

   - **Workaround:** Run it using a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
 if($_POST) { ... }
```

You dont have a form field called "submit" so this will always evaluate to false. Its the form field name attribute that is used in the $_POST array. Check your console to see what you are posting.

AND even on success you will get a blank page as your are not headering anything to the browser. Put an echo in your if block.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your php code, you need to add ";" in end of string declaration

```
$senderName = $_POST['senderName']
$senderUsermame = $_POST['senderUsermame']
$senderMethod = $_POST['senderMethod']
```

For development purposes (only for development) you can errors reporting to debug you code:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Give name to the submit button

```
<li><input type="submit" value="Trimite" name="submit" /></li>
```